# Can not lock mongochef to launcher in ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04

I downloaded `mongochef`. Then I go to its bin folder and run this

```
~ cd Program\ Files/studio-3t-5.3.5-linux-x64/bin
bin ./studio-3t.sh
```

Then on launcher I click add to dash + lock the launcher. Then I exit `mongochef`. I still see icon on launcher.

I click it to launch, it is pending. It is like it will start , it is getting bigger smaller it is just like it will start but it wont start.

This is desktop entry in `.local/share/applications/program.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry] 
Encoding=UTF-8 
Version=1.0 
Type=Application 
Name=Studio 3T for MongoDB - TRIAL LICENSE 
Icon=program 
Path=/home/caner/Program Files/studio-3t-5.3.5-linux-x64 
Exec=/home/caner/Program Files/studio-3t-5.3.5-linux-x64/bin/../jre/bin/java -Dprism.order=sw -jar /home/caner/Program Files/studio-3t-5.3.5-linux-x64/bin/../lib/data-man-mongodb-ent-5.3.5.jar 
StartupNotify=false 
StartupWMClass=Studio 3T 
OnlyShowIn=Unity; 
X-BAMFGenerated=true
```

this is `studio_3t.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry] 
Encoding=UTF-8 
Version=1.0 
Type=Application 
Name=Studio 3T for MongoDB - TRIAL LICENSE 
Icon=program 
Path=/home/caner/Program Files/studio-3t-5.3.5-linux-x64/bin 
Exec=/home/caner/Program Files/studio-3t-5.3.5-linux-x64/bin/../jre/bin/java -Dprism.order=sw -jar /home/caner/Program Files/studio-3t-5.3.5-linux-x64/bin/../lib/data-man-mongodb-ent-5.3.5.jar 
StartupNotify=false 
StartupWMClass=Studio 3T 
OnlyShowIn=Unity; 
X-BAMFGenerated=true
```